# Laravel or PhpStorm console message?

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-5.3

How can I remove this abnormal message?

It shows on every artisan command, for example when I run `artisan key:generate` it shows:

> php /home/www/gshop/artisan key:generate web.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpApplication
>   key [base64:pfMjYkUKgcghrUvzpE+3qOEPYrcu6tic2CO2AIkluj4=] set
>   successfully.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0 at 16:58:46. Execution time: 95 ms.

Show extra:

> web.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.phpweb.php

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem.
I created multiper file with live template that i create.
the problem that live template i create is i wrongly paste a text `web.php` before

```
<?php
/*
 * Created at : 2016-08-22
 * File Name : Web.php
 * By User : MyName
 */
?>
```

Problem Live Template with some comment code:

```
Web.php<?php
/*
 * Created at : 2016-08-22
 * File Name : 
 * By User : MyName
 */
?>
```

So everytime i use artisan, it will show all file that contain `web.php` before `<?php`

Sorry for the trouble , wish it can help anyone who facing this issue.

**How i found this error:**

I plan to reset phpstorm and create new project and move my code to new project, when i moving Live Template i just realise that mistake.
after i check back and remove all `web.php` from the file before `<?php`
it back to normal.